# ASP AJAX control/extender not displaying even with toolkitscriptmanager?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

So I have been trying to add a slider extender to one of my text box in my asp web forms application, but it just doesn't show up.  I am using visual studio 2013. After a lot research online, it seems that the solution is to replace the original script manager in site.master page with the AJAX toolkit scriptmanager. It still doesn't work for me.  I have tried it on a separate blank page, and it was fine. Once I wanted to add it to my project, it does not show up. I have tried it in both IE and Chrome. Here's what I have for my code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp"%>
....

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

....

```
<asp:SliderExtender ID="input_margin_SliderExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"   Maximum="100" Minimum="0" TargetControlID="input_margin">
```

I have tried putting the registration in the web config file and toolkitscriptmanager in the site.master file, and it makes no difference in results.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a reference to the AjaxControlToolkit to your project? Is the file in bin folder as well? I think an HtmlAgilityPack needs to be in the bin also.

For some reason I also had issues getting a simple AjaxControlToolkit to work on my site also. The solution for me was in the version of the toolkit I was using. Im using a godaddy site and tried using the latest release. It worked locally, but in production I was getting an error.

I ended up using older versions of the AjaxControlToolkit for 3.5. I believe it was this one http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091

That might be the problem